# Process StandartOutput.ReadLine() Hangs

Tags: c#, cmd, process, streamreader, readline

Hey i'm trying to read the output stream from cmd.exe
here is the code used

```
string r = string.Empty;
while(!cmd.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
     {
       r = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadLine(); /*the app hangs here after trying to read the last line*/
       MessageBox.Show(r);
     }
```

tried also that :

```
StreamReader reader = cmd.StandardOutput;
cmd.Close();
while(!reader.EndOfStream)
     {
       r = reader.ReadLine(); /*the app hangs here after trying to read the last line*/
       MessageBox.Show(r);
     }
```

same problem again.

i've replaced EndOfStream with peek()>=0 didn't work
tried to copy the base stream of cmd.StandardOutput into another stream using the method CopyTo() and it didn't work for me

**SOLUTION**
should add

```
            cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("exit");
```

before reading from the output stream

thanks to  Hans Passant

> That's expected, it is not going to exit that loop until you send it
>   the EXIT command so it closes its output stream. Not reading
>   StandardError is also a pretty good way to deadlock it. This only ever
>   works well when you use BeginOutput/ErrorReadLine().

*– Hans Passant*

Comment: That's expected, it is not going to exit that loop until you send it the EXIT command so it closes its output stream.  Not reading StandardError is also a pretty good way to deadlock it.  This only ever works well when you use BeginOutput/ErrorReadLine().

Comment: oh Thanks that's the solution

Answer (score -1):

ReadLine() returns the next line from the input stream, or null if the end of the input stream is reached. So you can do this:

```
var line = reader.ReadLine();
while(line != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show(line);
    line = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: not working because it hangs before returning anything